# How do I create an array of files based on rows in a database?

Tags: php

In PHP, I have an array of photos:

```
$file = array('p1.jpg','p2.jpg','p3.jpg');
```

Now I want to make this dynamic based on the rows in the database and the uploaded/deleted files. So for example if the user uploaded 10 photos and deleted the 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 9th one, the array would now be:

```
$file = array('p1.jpg','p4.jpg','p6.jpg','p7.jpg','p8.jpg','p10.jpg');
```

When the user uploads the file, the php script changes the filename to be "p" + whatever-row-the-database-is-at + ".jpg".

I'm assuming I would be using a loop to test whether that row exists in the database, okay I'm good up to there, but how do I make that output the proper array that I need?

Comment: I posted this way too late at night and my brain was fried.  I was walking around town today and figured it out, it's quite easy.  Sorry Stack Overflow community, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new to PHP?

```
$file = array();
while(.....) { //your loop goes here
  $file[] = ....; //add elements here
}
```

Comment: @Sepster I assumed he meant he knew how to make a loop, but didn't know how to add elements to an array.

Comment: Ah I see, fair enough too... it is a bit ambiguous as to what the actual question is.  I've deleted that comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping over the entire array to check if an entry still exists in the DB, it might just be quicker to actually delete the entire array and rebuild it using the results of a new DB query (as the DB query will be faster at finding the rows of interest, than you iteratively calling the DB to check if a row is still of interest).